# Unable to Override Cypress Intercept

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm having a really hard time trying to override an existing Intercept handler in my Cypress tests. I was using Cypress version 5 but I'm in the process of updating it. I'm currently on version 7, trying to get my tests to work before updating to newer versions.

I have checked existing questions here, but none of them worked for me, I even see contradictory information between them. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66765452/intercept-the-same-api-call-multiple-times-in-cypress) the accepted answer mentions that if you set up identical handlers with different aliases only the first one will fire BUT in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624787/cypress-intercept-execute-same-api-multiple-times-with-different-payload-in-sa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870276/cypress-7-0-override-responses-in-intercept) people indicate you can have similar handlers with different aliases and both will fire.

My code is pretty simple, this is a snippet :

```
...
describe("Loading Inventory", () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      cy.intercept("GET", "/ui_connect/inventory/**", {
         fixture: "operator/file.json",
         statusCode: 200,
     }).as("checkInventoryRequest");
   });

   it("My test", () => {
      cy.intercept("GET", "/ui_connect/inventory/**", {
         body: {},
         statusCode: 500,
      }).as("checkInventoryRequestWithError");

      cy.get("[data-test=inventory-button]").click();  // This triggers the request
       
      cy.wait("@checkInventoryRequestWithError").then(() => {
       
         cy.get(".e-alert-dialog")
            .contains("Inventory Generation Error")
            .should("be.visible");
         });
      });
   });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to override the Intercept that was defined in the `beforeEach`, but I have been unable to. I tried also naming both with the same tag, but the result is the same, my request always returns a 200 status code and the body from the fixture.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Request-phase) when executing the *Request Phase* it should take the last handler I defined, process it and end there, but that is not the behavior I'm seeing.

What could be the issue with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have is working with Cypress v7.7.0.

Here is a minimal, reproducible variant using the same intercept pattern, but triggering the fetch from the test instead of the app.

The `checkInventoryRequestWithError` alias is caught and processed correctly.

```js
describe('Loading Inventory', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/ui_connect/inventory/**', {
      fixture: 'operator/file.json',
      statusCode: 200,
    }).as('checkInventoryRequest')
  })

  it('My test', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '/ui_connect/inventory/**', {
      body: {},
      statusCode: 500,
    }).as('checkInventoryRequestWithError')

    // This triggers the request
    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.fetch('https://some-domain/ui_connect/inventory/1')
    })

    cy.wait('@checkInventoryRequestWithError').then(interception => {
      console.log(interception)
      expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(500)
    })
  })
})
```

If we change to `cy.wait('@checkInventoryRequest')`, the test fails.

You should note, the documentation is for Cypress v12.11.0 and unlikely to give you what you need to know for prior versions, particularly the `cy.intercept()` API which changed a lot over time.

Comment: You say the code I have works on Cypress 7.7.0, but that is not the case, at least not in my project, as I am using that exact version. Would you recommend jumping straight to the latest version (12)? I usually try to avoid that kind of big jumps, but I'm getting kind of desperate, so it might be worth giving it a try.

Comment: You can prove it to yourself - create a new project, install Cypress 7.7.0 and add the above test - it will pass.